# I try to write a function that will return the sum of all array elements that are equal to the number passed in the array. How can I do it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

this function return the sum of all elements in the array

````js
const array = [4, 7, 24, 7, 0, 10];
const number = 7;

function addTheSameNumbers1(number, array) {
    let count = array.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (array[i] === number) {
           return array.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

console.log(addTheSameNumbers1(number, array));```
````

Comment: Both `for` and `reduce` loop through the entire array. Your current algorithm iterates the array with `for` until it finds the number, and then sums up then entire array. You should do either one, not both: either iterate with `for` and *add* to a variable, which you `return` after the loop; *or* you iterate using `reduce` and then *conditionally* add `a` and `b` when it's the number you're looking for (hint: `a + (b === number ? b : 0`)…

Comment: Thank  for your response. I will try to resolve with your hint

Answer (score 1):

Your [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is summing all the values. This is how to sum a single number:

```js
const array = [4, 7, 24, 7, 0, 10];
const number = 7;

function addTheSameNumbers1(number, array) {
   return array.reduce((accum, val) =>
     val === number ? accum + val : accum
   , 0);
}

const result = addTheSameNumbers1(number, array);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. If I understand this code return sum of the array, but I need to return the sum of the elements that are equal with the number. In my case with 7. 7+7=14. Can you helm me?

Comment: The code in above answer returns `14`

Comment: Thank you very much. First time I dont write it corectly. It works

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the sum of the elements that have values which are the same to the length of their parent array. This code should do it.

```js
const filterAndSum = (numbers, query) => {
  return numbers
    .filter((n) => n === query)
    .reduce((n, total) => total + n, 0);
};

console.log(filterAndSum([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,2,1], 3))
```

First, it filters the elements which are not equal to the length of the parent array then gets the sum of the remaining elements. Note that validation is not implemented here, but I believe you could easily do that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to sum only the element of array that are equal to a number. In my case with 7, and the sum must be 14. 7+7 = 14. Cn you help me?

Comment: @Criss Sorry. Misunderstood you the first time. Already updated my answer. Goodluck!

Comment: Anytime, @Criss.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count the occurrence of variable and the multiple with the number

```html
<script>
const countOccurrences = (arr, val) => arr.reduce((a, v) => (v === val ? a + 1 : a), 0);
const array = [4, 7, 24, 7, 0, 10];
const number = 7;
var accur = countOccurrences(array, number);
console.log(accur);
console.log(accur * number);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `reduce` is to use a simple [for/of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loop to iterate over the numbers, and then add any found numbers to a `sum` variable.

```js
const array = [4, 7, 24, 7, 0, 10];
const number = 7;

function sumTheSameNumber(n, arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i of arr) {
    if (i === n) sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumTheSameNumber(number, array));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I test this code and it go. I am very glad, because I can not find the corect response.